# iPhone keyboard dictionary is not restored from iCloud backup

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, icloud, backup

I recently took my **iPhone SE** for a battery replacement. As with any other iPhone service, I was asked to backup everything. I did the backup in iCloud which includes everything that the backup allows.

I usually type in my native language using the English **QWERTY** keyboard, so I use tons of custom words in my every day conversation. 3 years worth of custom words were stored, and upon restoring the device from the backup after the service, POOFFF my words are gone! It is so frustrating that I need to type my custom words all again for auto-completion.

**QUESTIONS**

> 1. Does iOS really take backup of the custom words?
> 2. If not, is there any way to manually save and restore the iOS custom words dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can try SwiftKey. But the issue with 3rd party keyboards is that they might very well be transmitting whatever you type back to their servers. You never know. That's the reason I still haven't installed it on my iPhone. I had it installed on my Android because I controlled it using a firewall. iOS doesn't have any, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried that. But I am looking for ways to store and restore existing custom words from iOS native keyboard since it is my primary keyboard with many many words.

Comment: Do you have a MacBook? If so, can you see if the words are still in the settings?